# CUDA device properties for GTX 970

Tags: c++, windows, cuda

When calling

```
cudaError_t cuda_error;

int device;
cuda_error = cudaGetDevice(&device);
assert(cudaSuccess == cuda_error);

cudaDeviceProp prop;
cuda_error = cudaGetDeviceProperties(&prop, device);
assert(cudaSuccess == cuda_error);
```

on a GTX 970 with

- cuda driver 6.5.19,
- display driver version 343.98,
- Win7 Professional SP1 x64),

compiled with

```
-gencode=arch=compute_52,code="compute_52,sm_52"
```

i get following memory properties:

```
prop.totalGlobalMem == 0
```

and

```
prop.sharedMemPerBlock == 49152 (48k).
```

I expected the total memory to be ~ 4GB
and shared memory per block 96kB, as the GTX 970 uses GM204.

Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance for any support,
michel

Comment: The GeForce GTX980 and GTX970 have a CUDA 6.5 Toolkits with support for those specific GPUs, where the latest recommended cuda driver is v6.5.32.

Comment: Are you building this in Visual Studio? Is it an express version of VS?  Are you building a win32 project or an x64 project?  If you are building it as a win32 project, 4GB is not going to be a normally reportable number in a 32-bit quantity, it may show up as zero.  Regarding shared memory, sm_52 devices have 96KB shared memory **per SM** (i.e. per multiprocessor) but only 48KB shared memory is usable **per block**.  So the 48KB number is correct.

Comment: @robert crovella: 
I am building from command line, using VS 2012 Ultimate amd64, so there should be no problem with addressing 4GB. My main concern is (or was) the shared memory per block and you have answered this question.
If you post it as answer i will accept it.

Comment: If you are passing something like `--machine 32` on the command line, you will be building a 32-bit app and will have a 4GB limitation.

Comment: @RobertCrovella
    C:\...\nvcc.exe -gencode=arch=compute_52,code=\"compute_52,sm_52\" --use-local-env --cl-version 2012 -I__some_includes__ --use_fast_math -Xcudafe "--diag_suppress=field_without_dll_interface --diag_suppress=code_is_unreachable --diag_suppress=never_defined" **--machine 64** --compile -cudart static -DWin64 -DNDEBUG -D_MBCS -Xcompiler "/EHsc /W3 /nologo /O2 /MT " -o __a_file__.cu.o __a_file__.cu

Comment: How about print-out?  How are you printing out the `prop.totalGlobalMem` variable?  Are you handling it as a 64-bit quantity?  Otherwise, I'm out of ideas why it might be reporting 0.  You haven't provided a complete [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so there is just guesswork.

Comment: @RobertCrovella:  
Of course you're right, newbie mistake, used int instead of size_t. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My main concern is (or was) the shared memory per block

SM_52 (and SM_37) devices have [96KB shared memory](http://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/maxwell-most-advanced-cuda-gpu-ever-made/) available *per multiprocessor* (per SM) but only 48KB of this is usable by a single threadblock.  Therefore the reporting of the shared memory per block at 48KB is correct.

Quoting from the above linked blog:

> "Well, GM204 goes one better, upping that to 96KB of dedicated shared memory per SMM. There’s nothing you really need to change to take advantage of this feature: **the maximum shared memory per thread block is still 48KB**,"